# Is there a way to compile entityframework dataannotations in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC WebAPI to power a silverlight app.  The POCO objects are shared between the MVC and the Silverlight.  All the POCOs are in a .Net class library and I created a Silverlight class library with all the POCOs added as links so I can share the code.  Unfortunately this causes issues with data annotations, as the Silverlight class library can't reference EntityFramework.dll, and therefore cannot compile attribute such as [ForeignKey].

I've ended up having wrap all my annotations like this:

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT
        [ForeignKey("SecurityGroupID")]
#endif
        public virtual SecurityGroup SecurityGroup { get; set; }
```

Has anyone figured out a way to not have the #if !SILVERLIGHT wrapping all their annotations?
([Column], [Table], [ForeignKey], etc?).

One possible solution I've considered is just creating blank attributes with matching constructors in a child namespace (MyProject.FakeAttributes) and importing that namespace in the Silverlight version.  Does anyone see any problems with that solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have to recommend against using your Entities in Silverlight.  Entities often don't play nice with WCF because of things like lazy loading and cycles in the object graph.  Do yourself a favor and make dtos.

If you are not going to use dtos.  I'd go with the `#ifs` before I'd make fake attributes.

Comment: I think I may have some terminology messed up on my post.  I use EF 4.3.1 to interface with my database, but I load DTO objects.  I don't use any sort of navigation properties when I load the objects.  The properties do exist, but solely so that EF knows how to save the objects correctly.

Comment: The objects that are loaded from Entity Framework are Entities, even if you don't inherit from an "Entity" base class.  Your Entities can be POCO classes.

Comment: Also, I just noticed I left an important word out of my first sentence.  It should have read "I have to recommend _against_ using your Entities in Silverlight."  I've updated my answer.

Comment: How would I go about using DTOs?  Is it a different framework?

Comment: DTO stands for Data Transfer Object.  It would be a separate class that is only used for passing data to and from your client(Silverlight).  DTOs are usually POCO classes and in the case of WCF, the only attributes they should have are `DataContract` and `DataMember`.  However, these are not required.

Comment: So basically make a ToDTO() and LoadFromDTO(obj) classes on my EF POCOs?